# How to alter laravel middleware so failed ajax requests due to session timeout kick to login

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-middleware

I'm hoping someone can identify this problem and tell me where to look to fix it. Here's the scenario. I log into my site, and play with it for awhile, then leave the page open, and go to bed. When I wake up, the page is still open. If I click a link to a new page, the auth middleware recognizes I have timed out my session, am no longer authenticated, and kicks me to the login page to re-login. Great, that's what I want.

Now if it's the same scenario, except I wake up, the page is still open, and I click a button that sends an ajax request (to a route protected by auth middleware) the request simply fails, but doesn't recognize I'm no longer authenticated, and doesn't kick me back to the login page.

What can I change so that a failed ajax request, for the reason of not being authenticated, kicks me to the login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create a separate middleware called `ajaxAuthenticationCheck` that contains this in the `handle` method:

```
if ($request->ajax() && ! auth()->check()) {
    auth()->logout();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

And set it on every ajax route.